# Typescript - Generic function with an optional parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I have some trouble trying to type a **generic function with an optional parameter**

```
type Action<TParameters = undefined> = (parameters: TParameters) => void

const A: Action = () => console.log('Hi :)') 
// Ok, as expected

const B: Action<string> = (word: string) => console.log('Hello', word)  
// Ok, as expected

const C: Action<string> = (word: number) => console.log('Hello', word)  
// Error, as expected

const D: Action<string> = () => console.log('Hello')  
// Hum, what ?!? No error ?

const E: Action<string> = (word) => console.log('Hello', word)  
// No error as expected but the type inference of `word` is `any`, why ?
```

[Test it yourself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Action%3CTParameters%20%3D%20undefined%3E%20%3D%20(parameters%3A%20TParameters)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20A%3A%20Action%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log('Hi%20%3A)')%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20as%20expected%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20B%3A%20Action%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20(word%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20console.log('Hello'%2C%20word)%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%2C%20as%20expected%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20C%3A%20Action%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20(word%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20console.log('Hello'%2C%20word)%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%2C%20as%20expected%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20D%3A%20Action%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log('Hello')%20%20%2F%2F%20Hum%2C%20what%20%3F!%3F%20No%20error%20%3F%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20E%3A%20Action%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20(word)%20%3D%3E%20console.log('Hello'%2C%20word)%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%20as%20expected%20but%20the%20type%20inference%20of%20%60word%60%20is%20%60any%60%2C%20why%20%3F%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Comment: `word` is `string` in the final example you posted (see the test it yourself link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `D` type checks is that ignoring extra parameters happens often in JavaScript. With regard to the parameters, a function `f` is considered a subtype of a function `g` as long as each parameter of `f` is compatible with the corresponding parameter of `g`. Any extra arguments in `f` are ignored. See 'Comparing two functions' in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

(And as noted by @david-sherret, `E` works as you would expect, with `word: string`.)